# Google GData for Picasa in Maven

Tags: maven, gdata, picasa

This question has been asked many times before, but all answers seem to be outdated.

Are Google's GData artifacts (most notably Picasa's) in Maven?

They use not to be, so there were alternatives like http://code.google.com/p/mandubian-mvn/
and https://github.com/eburtsev/Google-Data-APIs-Mavenized

But they all seem to stop being updated around GDate version 1.41 from 2010. At that time Google says they released their jars to maven, and here are the official setup instructions for Maven.
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Maven

But this artifact does not seem to contain the PicasewebService class that is in the documentation.
https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java#ClientLogin

However the samples project contains a lib folder with all required jars, and the photos jar has the PicasawebService class.
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list

So it seems there is a difference from what is in the samples' lib folder and what is in Maven.

Hence the question; are the jars in samples somewhere in Maven?

Comment: Yes, please pass any info along that you can. A year ago I created an Android project that simply downloads an image from a Picasa album. All I could find was some esoteric sample in some library that I had to install manually. A year later and I don't see that anything's change. You and I seem to be the only people wanting to access Picasa from Android.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled in a similar issue. I see this is a stale thread but I'll just post it here for reference.

It appears that gdata is not in maven central repository but api-client is. There are 2 different things, gdata being somewhat deprecated (not officially deprecated at the time of this writing but discontinued with the exception of critical bug fixes).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this maven repo http://maven.burtsev.net. See detailed description [here](http://burtsev.net/en/2012/01/29/149/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link. I settled on uploading the jars in the samples to my own repository, under a custom name.